# React Routes redirect to external URL for Auth links

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an example of the code where I am trying to redirect users which not log in yet. I am using external auth in order to send the user to login via 3rd party auth system. I know that react-routes have `Redirect` option, and I understand that they redirect only to pathnames. Is there a way to make it so that redirect happened with `window.assign` which redirect users right away to a different page?

Thank you in advance!

```
const ProtectedRoute = (auth, component: Component, ...rest) => {
  return <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => auth.isAuthenticated()
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: 'http://example.com/',
          state: { from: props.location },
        }}
      />
    }
  />;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could evaluate the logging props in your component's `componentDidMount` hook and use window.location to redirect to entirely different URL. Eg:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }
    window.location.assign('http://example.com/');
}
```

Comment: Does the component should be `React.PureComponent`? so that I am calling as much code as possible?

Comment: Need not be, you can evaluate this in any regular component as well.

Comment: yes, it works fine when I redirected the user to the new page, the eventhoug page was blank it still rendered what I actually needed